# Filling default missing/arguments from args/kwargs and function signature in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function `fun` and objects `args` and `kwargs`, and I'd like to get a dictionary of arguments and values that would be available in  `fun` if I called it `fun(*args, **kwargs)` (without actually calling `fun`). In other words I would need to bind elements of `args` to parameter names, and fill parameters missing in `args` and `kwargs` with default values

In Python 3.3 there's a `inspect.signature` that can help, but I'm working in Python 2.7, does anyone have a pointer to the code that can work for this task in 2.7?

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: Python 2 has `inspect.getargspec()`. This is not as full featured as `inspect.signature` however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, I was hoping someone did a backport, or rewrote the logic in <100 LoC snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new [PEP 362 *Function Signature Object*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) functionality has been backported to 2.7 as the [`funcsigs` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs):

```
try:
    from inspect import signature
except ImportError:
    from funcsigs import signature 

sig = signature(yourfunction)
boundargs = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
```